# When will ros.org be back up?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The main [website/wiki](http://ros.org), [code.ros.org](http://code.ros.org), and [willowgarage.com](http://willowgarage.com) all seem to be down.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12918/when-will-ros.org-be-back-up?/) by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2264 on 2012-02-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The short answer: yes, they will be back up.

In the meantime, here's a mirror: http://ros.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/roswiki/

You can also set up your own mirror. Just follow [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/977/create-a-rosorg-wiki-mirror) answer(you won't be able to do so while the main site is down though).

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1